# Cluster position units in fastq file

Tags: bioinformatics

I have a fastq file with headers that include positions in the same format as the [wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTQ_format#Illumina_sequence_identifiers) for fastq:

```
@HWUSI-EAS100R:6:73:941:1973#0/1
```

I know that `x=941` and `y=1973`, but what are the units? Microns? Some illumina distance?

If there was another cluster at `x=931` and `y=1973`, would they be 10 microns apart?

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Contacted illumina support and they said the information I needed, such as dimension of the tile viewing area or zoom of the microscope, was "considered proprietary," which is frustrating.

Comment: Maybe better asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org).  AFAIK, it should be unitless. I would expect that different flow cells and sequencers have different cluster densities.  You'd need to read the details on the flow cells to deduce the physical distances.

Comment: Thanks, I've opened the question on biostars https://www.biostars.org/p/302867/

Comment: @merv or here https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions (but don't cross-post)

Comment: Also, I This should be split into question and answer to fit better the rules of the site (nothing wrong with answering your own questions, but to make it clearer for readers what is your solution).

Answer (score 2):

As a short term solution I've used the optimal cluster density provided [here](https://support.illumina.com/bulletins/2016/10/cluster-density-guidelines-for-illumina-sequencing-platforms-.html) to estimate the size of 1 pixel in microns.

I have plotted the (x,y) positions of the clusters from a given tile to get a figure like this:
[image: tile_positions]

Steps:

1. Estimate the area of the viewing window from the number of clusters present
2. Convert from mm^2 to um^2
3. Convert to um^2 to radius of the window in um
4. Calculate the radius of the window in pixels along the x dimension
5. Divide the two to get the number of pixels per um

Code:

```
print 'For {} clusters, assuming optimal is {}'.format(num_clusters, num_optimal)
for perc in perc_optimal:
    mm_sqr = num_clusters/(perc*num_optimal)
    um_sqr = mm_sqr*1e6
    um_radius = np.sqrt(um_sqr/np.pi)

    px_radius = (pos['x'].max()-pos['x'].min())/2
    px_to_um = px_radius/um_radius

    out = ('At {}% optimal, tile r is {} um, pixel r is {} px,'
           'so {} px is 1 um'.format(perc*100,um_radius,px_radius,px_to_um))

    print out
```

Output:

```
For 531143 clusters, assuming optimal is 900000
At 10.0% optimal, tile r is 1370.59625256 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 10.2123436963 px is 1 um
At 20.0% optimal, tile r is 969.157904453 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 14.4424349589 px is 1 um
At 30.0% optimal, tile r is 791.314115365 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 17.6882981464 px is 1 um
At 40.0% optimal, tile r is 685.298126279 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 20.4246873926 px is 1 um
At 50.0% optimal, tile r is 612.949278085 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 22.8354947145 px is 1 um
At 60.0% optimal, tile r is 559.543577023 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 25.0150311339 px is 1 um
At 70.0% optimal, tile r is 518.036690306 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 27.0193217236 px is 1 um
At 80.0% optimal, tile r is 484.578952226 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 28.8848699179 px is 1 um
At 90.0% optimal, tile r is 456.865417519 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 30.6370310889 px is 1 um
At 100.0% optimal, tile r is 433.420591057 um, pixel r is 13997 px,so 32.2942663288 px is 1 um
```

This is all very rough and I'd appreciate a different answer, but maybe this helps someone